# Confused on book's answer about span(S)

Tags: linear-algebra

A problem in my book wants us to say whether the set $S = \{(-1, 2), (2, -4)\}$ spans $\Bbb R^2$. Their answer is as follows:

> $S$ does not span $\Bbb R^2$ because only vectors of the form $t(1,-2)$ are in $span(S)$.

Did they mean to say $t(-1, 2)$? I could understand how that would be the span of $S$, but otherwise I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the same: $t(-1, 2)=(-t)(1, -2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$(1,-2) = -(-1,2)$, so the spans of $(1,-2)$ and $(-1,2)$ are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors of the form $t(-1,2)$ are the same than the vectors of the form $t(1,-2)$, because $t$ may have any value in $\Bbb R$, so you may choose $-t$ instead of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

A general condition for the two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to span the space itself is they be linearly independent. The vectors in question are not, so they don't span the underlying space.